# Transcendence à la Liouville

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory, transcendence

Let $\alpha\in\overline{\mathbb Q}^*$. How to prove that for a non ultimately constant sequence $(\varepsilon_n)_n$ with $\varepsilon_n\in\{0,1\}$, the number $\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{\varepsilon_n}{\alpha^{n!}}$ is transcendental? If $\alpha$ was in $\mathbb R$, Liouville's theorem would give the result immediately. But what about for a non-real $\alpha$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to assume $|\alpha|>1$ for this sum to converge. I think Liouville's theorem should have a variant for arbitrary number fields, which would imply that if for some number field $K$ (here we'd take $K=\mathbb Q(\alpha)$) a number $\beta$ has too good approximations by elements of $K$, then $\beta$ is transcendental. I don't know off-hand a reference for such a result though.

Comment: Liouville's inequality provides a bound on the absolute value of the difference of two algebraic numbers (in terms of their height and degree). More general versions give a bound for a polynomials evaluated at algebraic numbers. Chapter 3 of Waldschmidt's book "Diophanitine approximation on linear algebraic groups" is a great source for that.